# Why is my ssh connection failing?

Tags: ssh, cygwin

I'm trying to use SSH authentication between my WinXP desktop running Cygwin and a Mac laptop, and for the life of me, I can't get it working. My public key is on the macbook in the authorized_keys directory, and my private key is sitting there, all nice and happy in my ~/.ssh folder.

Here are the relevant lines from running ssh -vv user@server

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/cygwin/home/beerhalj/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /c/cygwin/home/beerhalj/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /c/cygwin/home/beerhalj/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: read PEM private key done: type DSA
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
```

It looks like my server sends a publickey packet, then doesn't send a packet and disables. Why? Or, what possible things should I try? Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

As per SparX suggestion, I cat'd my sshd_config and there are only three non-comment lines

```
Protocol 2
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
Subsystem sftp/usr/libexec/sftp-server
```

Comment: Adding SSH configuration of target machine will be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the authorized_keys file as well as the .ssh folder and your home folder aren't writable by anyone but yourself. Sshd disregards it otherwise.

Comment: I'm not really a linux guy, so what's the number for that? I definitely screwed this up, as I definitely did a chmod 777 authorized_keys at some point

Comment: Found it, chmod 600. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add a follow-up answer, just to keep in mind in the future. As of a few years ago, and this is probably still true, there still doesn't exist a perfect mapping of NT/AD style permissions to Unix permissions. I remember having a problem that if my .ssh files resided on a network drive, and were being used under cygwin, the permissions *couldn't* be set properly on the files, because the permissions model didn't allow for it.

It's possible to get burned by this and have it stump you for hours. However, I am guessing your current case that your files reside on a local drive, and this isn't affecting you.